# Difficulty in showing that $u$ is harmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-functions, borel-measures, poisson-integrals

> Let $\mu$ be a complex regular Borel measure on $\mathbb T.$ Define a function $u : \mathbb D \longrightarrow \mathbb C$ by $$u \left (re^{i \theta} \right ) = \int_{\mathbb T} \frac {1 - r^2} {1 + r^2 - 2r \cos (\theta - t)}\ d\mu \left (e^{it} \right ),\ 0 \leq r \lt 1,\ 0 \leq \theta \lt 2 \pi.$$
>
> Show that $u$ is a harmonic function.

One way to do that is to interchange the Laplacian and the integral operator and then figure out whether the integrand is harmonic or not. Other way is to use the tricks in complex analysis to see whether $u$ is the real or imaginary part of an analytic function. So in order to apply the first trick in some sense we would like to have a sufficient condition for which the Laplacian operator can be brought inside the integral sign. For the second trick we need to find a suitable analytic function such that one of whose components is the function $u$ we have started with. Unfortunately none of the approach seems easy to me. Could anyone give me some suggestion in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The integrand is the Poisson kernel. Do you know it's alternative expression? You can write it as $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb Z} r^{|n|} e^{in(\theta - t)}.$ Possibly this expression of the integrand is easier to deal with.

Comment: Standard text book material. See Rudin's RCA, for example.

Comment: The integrand is equal ${\rm Re} {1+ze^{-it}\over 1-ze^{-it}}$ for $z=re^{i\theta}.$ Hence $$u(z)={\rm Re}\int\limits_{\mathbb{T}} {1+ze^{-it}\over 1-ze^{-it}}\,d\mu(e^{it})$$ The integrand is holomorphic in the open unit disc, so the integral represents a holmorphic function, and its real part is harmonic.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc$:$ Is it always true that integral of a holomorphic function is holomorphic where the integral is taken with respect to any complex regular Borel measure? I am not quite familiar with these stuffs. Sorry for that.

Comment: You can do it by hand: if $f(z)=\int\limits_a^bF(z,t)d\mu(t)$ then $f'(z)=\int\limits_a^b{\partial F\over \partial z}(z,t)d\mu(t)$. It suffices  that $F(z,t)$ and  ${\partial F\over \partial z}(z,t)$ are continuous.

Comment: You can do it by hand: if $f(z)=\int\limits_a^b F(z,t)\,d\mu(t),$ where $z\mapsto F(z,t)$ are holomorphic for $|z|<1$ and $F(z,t),$ 
${\partial F\over \partial z}(z,t)$ are continuous as function of two variables, one complex the other real.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc$:$ I presume that you are using Leibnitz rule for differentiation under the integral sign. The results are usually proved for Lebesgue measure on some interval say $[a,b]$ and I don't know whether similar version is true for any complex Borel measures. However complex Borel measures can be broken down to it's real and imaginary parts each of which is a signed measure and hence both of the measures admit Jordan decomposition into difference of two positive Borel measures and as a result the said theorems are still valid since Borel measures are restrictions of Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 0):

For each fixed $z \in \mathbb D$ we can define a new complex measure $\nu_z$ as $d\nu_z = (e^{it}+z)\ d\mu.$ Then the said integral is the real part of the following integral $$u(z) = \int_{\mathbb T} \frac {d\nu_z(e^{it})}{e^{it}-z}$$ and it is easy to show that given $a\in \mathbb D$ and $r\gt 0$ with $B(a,r) \subseteq \mathbb D$ the infinite series $\sum\limits_{n= 0}^{\infty} \frac {(z-a)^n}{(e^{it}-a)^{n+1}}$ converges uniformly to the integrand $\frac {1} {e^{it} - z}$ on $\mathbb T$ for each fixed $z \in B(a,r)$ and hence $u(z)$ admits a power series expansion about $a$ on $B(a,r)$ and therefore $u$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb D$ (since $a \in \mathbb D$ was arbitrary). Since real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic the result follows.